# How to do telemetry HealthCheck in java?

Tags: java, spring, health-monitoring

I am working on one Spring boot application having controller class containing multiple API calls. I had done HealthCheck on overall project i.e getting CPU utlization,Memory used,DB Latency,etc. used by project.Now,I wants to do healthcheck on each function or each call i.e I want to know which call is using much CPU,Memory which is termed as telemetry. 
Any suggestions or links providing a way to do it injava?

Comment: Did you check spring-boot-actuator?

Comment: @deathangel908 I didn't checked , but upto my knowledge it just provides class level info ,nothing about telemetry. Let me check it again . Any other suggestion

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to determine how much CPU/Memory each call uses, since  java (jmx) doesn't provide such information. So tools won't be able to get it as well.

Comment: yes exactly ,needed to do some custom implementation .

Comment: What I'm trying to say there's no way to implement it.